# Symfony 1.4.8 not working in PHP 5.3.4?

Tags: php53

I have installed PHP version 5.3.4, and working on Symfony 1.4.8 with Propel as ORM. But while installing Symfony project, it is giving me error. When i use the command to build database it giving me error, i.e when i use Propel command. Is propel, not supporting PHP 5.3? what can be done to resolve that?

Previously i was using XAMP 1.7.1 which had PHP 5.2.9. But when i installed the latest XAMP which had PHP 5.3.

Comment: What command are you using and what error did you get?

Comment: @DerfK propel:insert-sql dont work, shows some error..

Comment: What exactly is the text of "some error"?

Comment: @DerfK there were many of them coming..cant just past it here.. :)

Comment: Without seeing errors one can't reason about what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: yeah thats right, errors were some magic_quotes_gpc is deprecated in PHP 5.3. I know that some of the methods in Symfony is been deprecated in 5.3 version, hence i have to use the downgraded version for my project.

Comment: What command line command are you using exactly and what is its output?
symfony 1.4.8/1.4.9 working fine with recent php 5.3 on our machines.

Comment: yes i am using the same propel command as given in documentation.

Comment: that are 'php symfony propel:build-sql', 'php symfony propel:insert-sql', 'php symfony propel:build-model'

Comment: We can't see the propel command in your documentation. Can you please give some more detailed info for this question. Such as, what commands are you running, when you run them and if they fail, what errors are you seeing in the php logs, as well as you messages log.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with XAMPP and PHP 5.3.4 when you install the newest xampp version (PHP 5.3.5) the problem is solved and there are no problems.

Best way you update symfony to the newest version if its possible in your system.

Comment: i have tried it with Symfony 1.4.11, which is the stable version, but still not working for me.

Comment: Have you installed the last XAMMP Version? [Here](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-windows.html)

Comment: i installed the latest version, which gave error, then downgraded my XAMP version, and it started working.

Comment: Ich have installed the last XAMMP version and work with it and symfony. I have the problem with the version before. But in the newest Version i have no problemes. Have you enabled error_reporting and dreprecated Messages?